# Absolute minimum testing required to make it easier to upgrade Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to start a new angularjs project, but I am weary of building something that will break when upgrading to the latest version.

Is there a best practice in terms of what you should always test to ensure upgrades go as smoothly as possible?

Would this be more of an integration test to test for functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Tests at all 'levels' from unit to integration/system tests will give you the ability to at least give newer versions a "smoke test" and have some degree of confidence in the result.

Typically you'd also pay close attention to the release notes and make a judgement call on what areas of code to inspect / test more rigorously.